# Display two divs side by side. If one div extends second div it should take the width 100%

Tags: html, css, sass

here I'm attaching the image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ7F6.png) to explain my question more understandable.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you can use below concept to add the class based on div length

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($(".column").length == 1){
$('.column').addClass('column-width');
}
else{
$('.column').addClass('column-size-half');
}

})
```

```css
.column{border:1px solid #ccc}
.column-width{100%;}
.column-size-half{width:49%; display:inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">Column wrapper1</div>
<div class="column">Column wrapper2</div>
```